# How to Separate values from any array into multiple array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I Have array like this.

```
 var array= ["4220495|1", "4220495|2"]
```

I want these values in separate array like this

```
var firstArray=["4220495", "4220495"];
var secondArray=["1", "2"];
```

If you want more information let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the values and get the result

```js
var array= ["4220495|1", "4220495|2"];
var firstArray = [];
var secondArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
  var itemArray = array[i].split('|');
  firstArray.push(itemArray[0]);
  secondArray.push(itemArray[1])
}
console.log(firstArray);
console.log(secondArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstArr = [];
var secondArr = [];
["4220495|1", "4220495|2"].map(function(value) {
   var splitted = value.split('|');
   firstArr.push(splitted[0]);
   secondArr.push(splitted[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do this.  Here's one:

```
var array= ["4220495|1", "4220495|2"];
var firstArray = array.map(function(v){ return v.split("|")[0] });
var secondArray= array.map(function(v){ return v.split("|")[1] });
```

Comment: The other solutions are more efficient, as they only require one iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more generic solution for any split length.

```js
var array = ["4220495|1", "4220495|2"],
    firstArray = [],
    secondArray = [];

function arraySplit(array, target) {
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        a.split('|').forEach(function (b, i) {
            target[i].push(b);
        });
    });
}

arraySplit(array, [firstArray, secondArray]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(firstArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(secondArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```